# How to implement ODBC connection for Pyspark?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, teradata, pyodbc

I am using the following code to connect PySpark with **Teradata** server:

```
import pyodbc
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

appName = "PySpark Teradata Example"
master = "local"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()


link = 'DRIVER={DRIVERNAME};DBCNAME={hostname};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}'.format(DRIVERNAME='Teradata Database ODBC Driver 17.10',\
                                                                       hostname='192.168.xx.xxx',uid='dbc', Database='AdventureWorksDW'\
                                                                       ,pwd='dbc')
conn = pyodbc.connect(link)
cus=conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * from AdventureWorksDW.DimAccount"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
print(df)
cus.close()
conn.close()
```

This works, but I need to replace plain Pandas with **Pyspark.Pandas** API.

When I replace `import pandas as pd`  with  `import pyspark.pandas as pd` ,

I get the error -

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

What other changes do I need to make to the code?

**Note** - I know I can use JDBC connection, but the requirement is for ODBC.